# java panel layout dock

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout, dock

I'm having problem with the "dock" in java panel. I have UI like

[image]

the panel has a slide bar, a button and a scroll view, i.e. the while area above, with GirdBagLayout, (I also tried BorderLayout but won't work either). below it is another panel, both panel are placed in a parent panel with GridBagLayout.

When I click the "more" button, I want to extend the height of the panel to 3*original height to let the scrollview show more stuff vertically. and of course I want the slide bar and button still at the bottom of the panel. I call resize on the panel but I got this:

[image]

it shows that the scrollview is longer than before but was cut, and the bar and button remain at the same place. and my question is how I can put the slide bar and button always at the botton of the panel and show the scrollview correctly.

Comment: BorderLayout.SOUTH comes to mind but better start by editing and  adding the handler code for your "More" button.

Comment: Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) as an edit to your original question. Please avoid trying to post code in comments as they lose their formatting and are unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

well, answer to my own question:

have to set up the layout again and call revalidate() and repaint().

Comment: It isn't necessary to set up a layout if it has already been set correctly.

Comment: if you're needing to set the layout to the same one that it was previously, then you've got a bug somewhere in your program that you've not yet addressed. Without an [sscce](http://sscce.org), all I can say is there's a bug, but I doubt that we can help you further. Again consider creating and posting one of these.